# cqlsh command is not running

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to conecting to Cassandra with cqlsh but no able to connect while the Cassandra service is running. Below is the status of Cassandra service.

```
(base) kuldeep@kuldeep-OptiPlex-3050:~$ systemctl status cassandra
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-12-28 18:13:35 IST; 25min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 21770 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 52 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/cassandra.service
        └─21858 java -ea -da:net.openhft... -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-Us

Dec 28 18:13:35 kuldeep-OptiPlex-3050 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
Dec 28 18:13:35 kuldeep-OptiPlex-3050 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

But when I tried to connect to Cassandra with `cqlsh` I am getting the following error.

```
(base) kuldeep@kuldeep-OptiPlex-3050:~$ cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 115, in <module>
  from cqlshlib import cqlhandling, cql3handling, pylexotron
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib/cqlhandling.py", line 22, in <module>
  from cassandra.metadata import cql_keywords_reserved
ImportError: No module named cassandra.metadata
```

After doing some research someone suggests me to install the Cassandra-driver and I follow the same.

```
(base) kuldeep@kuldeep-OptiPlex-3050:~$ pip install cassandra_driver
Requirement already satisfied: cassandra_driver in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.6 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cassandra_driver) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cassandra_driver) (3.1.1)
```

But again I am getting the same error.

```
cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 115, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cqlhandling, cql3handling, pylexotron
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib/cqlhandling.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cassandra.metadata import cql_keywords_reserved
ImportError: No module named cassandra.metadata
```

can anyone help me to getting out of this. Any help will be greatly apprreciated.

Comment: create a separate conda environment with Python 2.7, and try from there

Comment: seems issue with version of cqlsh. Please check versions.